# HELPP... Prove the equivalence: ACB = 30 only if BD = 2*MD

Tags: geometry, triangles, equivalence-relations, median

Please help mee!!!!!!
In triangle $ABC$, $BAC=90^\circ$, $M$ is its middle $ [BC]$ and $BD\perp AM$, $D\in(AC)$. Prove the equivalence: ::
$$
ACB = 30^\circ \iff BD = 2\cdot MD
$$

> You can see my drawing down and also my ideas...
> [image]
> [image]

As you can see I could demonstrate the fact that if $ACB$ is $30^\circ$ then $BD=2\cdot MD$
But I don't know how to do the opposite of it. I know that usually the idea is the same...but no idea came into my mind.
Any idea is welcome! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

,[image]

As cab be seen in figure,E is mid point of BD, so :

$EM||AC$

$AM\bot ED$, so quadrilateral AEMD is rhombus and :

$ME=AD=ED=AE=MD=\frac {BD}2\Rightarrow BD=2 MD$

Also:

$\widehat{DBM}=30^o$

Triangle BAD and BMD are congruent, because:

$\angle ADB=\angle BDM=60^o$ , so $\angle ABD=\angle DBC$, which gives:

$\angle ABC=60^o \Rightarrow \angle ACB=30^o$

Update: Answer to your questions in your comment:

1- Itriangle BDC, the midpoints of sides BD and  BC are conneted so $EM||DC$. We have:

$AE=\frac{BD}2=EM=ND=ED$

This together with facts $ED\bot MA$ and $EM||AD$ are enough to conclude that AEMD is a rhombus. So $MD||AE$.

2- If $BD=2 MD$ that means in right angle triangle BDM:

$\angle DBM=30^o \Rightarrow \angle BDM=60^o$

In rhombus AEMD. diagonal ED bisects angle ADM, so $\angle ADM=120^o$

This angle is exterior to to right angle triangle MDC, where:

$\angle DMC=90^o \Rightarrow \angle MCD=120-90=30^o $

Comment: ummm... this is the solve of the part I did. Thank you for the new idea! But, can you help me in if BD=2MD we have to show that ACB=30?

Comment: also, how did you showed that AEMD is a parallelogram

Comment: ???????????????????

Comment: @IonelaBuciu, please see the update.

Comment: sorry for not understamding, hope im not that bold, but how can i demonstrate what you said with the 4 triangle congruence?? I will vote this answer as the right idea. Thank youu!!!

Comment: "if two sides of a quadrilateral are parallel and also their diagonals are perpendicular, then it is a rhombus" is certainly false. The correct statement is "if both pairs of opposite sides of a quadrilateral are parallel and also their diagonals are perpendicular, then it is a rhombus"

Comment: @DS so can you help me with a new idea...if we can show that AEMD is parallelogram then is going to be easy....

Comment: What congruence....can you post an answer plzzzz??? Thank you from the bottom of my heart!!

Comment: @sirous ????????

Comment: @IonelaBuciu, see my edit, I showed the reason for AEMD is a rhombus.

Comment: @IonelaBuciu, see my edit, I showed the reason for AEMD is a rhombus.

Comment: @sirous Sorry....how do you know that EM=BD/2. There are some missing steps , i think.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same figure used by sirous since I have no means to draw a diagram now:

[image]

Due to the mid-point theorem, we have that $EM||AC$. Also, we have $AE = BD/2 = MD$. Thus, quad. $AEMD$, is a parallelogram or an isosceles trapezium. Suppose it is an isosceles trapezium. Then $\angle AEM = \angle EMD$.
But $\angle AEM = \angle DEA + \angle DEM = \angle DEA + \angle EMD > \angle EMD$. We arrive at a contradiction, and hence $AEDM$ is a parallelogram. 
Since the diagonals are perpendicular, it is also a rhombus. We can complete the required proof from here in many ways.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I would never thought of this!!!